# Prove that $\exists z \in \mathbb{R} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ [\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x) \iff x \neq z]$

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have been struggling with knowing when it is okay to reuse variables within a proof. For example, in my proof below is it valid to existentially instantiate $y$ after I state $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x)$?

Proof: Let $z = 0$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ be arbitrary. Suppose $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x)$. Thus, we can choose a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y-x = y/x$.  Suppose $x = z$. Since $z=0$, $x=0$. Then we have $y-0=y/0$, but $y/0$ is undefined, so we have a contradiction. Thus, $x \neq z$. Therefore, if $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x)$, then $x \neq z$.

Now suppose $x \neq z$. Let $y = \frac{x}{1-1/x}$. $y$ is defined since $x \neq z = 0. $ Then we have $y-x=\frac{x}{1-1/x}-x = \frac{x}{1-1/x} - \frac{x-1}{1-1/x} = \frac{1}{1-1/x} = \frac{x}{1-1/x} * \frac{1}{x} = \frac{y}{x}$. Thus, $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x)$. Therefore, if $x\neq z$, then $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x)$.

Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ [\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x) \iff x \neq z]$. Thus, there $\exists z \in \mathbb{R} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ [\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y-x = y/x) \iff x \neq z]$. $\square$

Comment: If $z = 0$ then $x=1 \ne z$ would mean that $y-1 = \frac y1$ will have a solution.  Does it?

Comment: @fleablood No :(. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You "Let $z=0$" without being assured that this is a witness for the existential.

Comment: You did an if, but not the only if.  You must have $y-x = \frac yx$ has a solution *whenever* $x\ne z$.  So let's assume $x \ne z$ for a moment and find that solution.  If you try to find that solution, you will discover precisely when solutions do and don't exist.

Comment: Oh... also $x=0 \not \in \mathbb R^{+}$

Comment: I tried to let $x=z$ for contradiction. Would $x = 0 \notin \mathbb{R}^+$ be sufficient to show a contradiction?

Comment: No. Not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, $x$ can be any positive real.

So let's solve for $y$ when $y - x = \frac yx$ so $y-\frac yx = x$ so $y(1-\frac 1x) = x$.

Assuming $1-\frac 1x \ne 0$. then $y =\frac x{1-\frac 1x}$ will be a solution.

But if $1-\frac 1x = 0$ or in other words if $x = 1$ then $y-x = \frac yx$ would mean $y-1 = y$ which has no solutions.

So for every $x\in \mathbb R^+$ then $y-\frac yx = x$ will have a solution if and only if $x\ne 1$.

So $z = 1$ is such a number that does what you want.

.....

The problem with $z = 0$ is that,1) $x =z=0\not \in \mathbb R^+$ and 2) yes, if $x=0$ then $y-x =\frac yx$ has not solution, but $x\ne 0$ does not guarantee a solution.  You have the "if" but not the "only if".

Comment: Why is $x=z=0 \notin \mathbb{R}^+$ a problem? This was for a contradiction (suppose not $x \neq z$). Is it automatically wrong to assume a statement if it clashes with something given?

Comment: You don't have assurance that $\forall x\in\Bbb R^+~(\exists y~(y-x=y/x)\leftrightarrow x\neq 0)$ would be true. (In fact, it is not.)

Comment: Ohhhh I see now. Thank you for the insight! I got used to existential statements with simple equations and forgot the basic rules.

Answer (score 1):

To prove an existence, you must either **directly *construct* an example**, or indirectly prove that non-existence *reduces to absurdity*.   NB: for this exercise you should do the former.

You *may not* just "Let $z=0$," because you have no *assurance* that zero may be a witness to the existential.

Your task is to **find** *some* real value, $z$, for which *any arbitrary* positive real value, $x$, will have a real valued solution for $y$ in $(y-x=y/x)$ *exactly when* $x\neq z$ .

> Well we know that for any positive $x$, the $y$ solution to $y-x=y/x$ is $x^2/(x-1)$.  So ...

Comment: I am a little confused now. This exercise is from "How To Prove It" by Velleman. Whenever we have an existence proof, e.g. $\exists y P(y)$, the proof formula always starts with "Let y = something", then we prove $P(y)$ to verify the existence. The "Let $z=0$" step of my proof is wrong because that value of $z$ is incorrect, but the proof structure is still correct, right?

Comment: Since the "Let $z=0$" was incorrect, my proof should have some flaw in the "if and only if" portion of the proof. Somehow I made the proof work out, so there is still some major flaw that I am missing.

Comment: Your proof does not work. It is *not* true that for *all* positive $x$ that $x\neq 0$ is equivalent to $\exists y~(y-x=y/x)$.  There exists a value for $x$ which makes the equivalence false.

Comment: Yes, I know now that the whole proof does not work, but where specifically does it go wrong after the "Let $z = 0$"? What I meant by "work out" was that somehow I did not reach something absurd while using an incorrect value for $z$. If one starts an existence proof ($\exists y P(y)$) with an incorrect value of $y$, shouldn't it be impossible to show that $P(y)$?

Comment: Is it the "Suppose $x=z$" sentence that is incorrect?